# How to set "Use System Certificates" with WifiEnterpriseConfig

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifi

I would like to configure an Enterprise WiFi network for the user of my app.

Therefor the user has to enter his username and password, the rest should be handled by the App.
The authentication is handled by a RADIUS server (FreeRadius 3), the server uses a certificate issued by LetsEncrypt (so there is no need to import my own CA cert).

When I manually configure the network via the settings app, I choose "USe System Certificates" as CA certificate and set the domain to "example.org".

How can I set this option using WifiEnterpriseConfig?

This is my code so far:

```
WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();
wfc.SSID = "\"SomeSSID\"";
wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;                            
wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);

wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);

wfc.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(username);
wfc.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password); 


wfc.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
wfc.enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2);

// How can I set "use system certificates"?
// wfc.enterpriseConfig.setCaCertificate(?); ???
wfc.enterpriseConfig.setDomainSuffixMatch("example.org");
```

After executing this code, the network is configured but CA Cert is set to "no validation" and the domain is not set.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you get any results?? I faced the same problem. Even though send CA using setCaCertificate method, i get CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error.

Comment: No, I just kept it the way it is and use "no validation"

Comment: I am faceing same issue, Did you get any result??