# How to connect to a radius-authenticated Wifi device on Android 10(Android Q) or later

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I am creating a connection process to a radius authenticated Wifi device.

I tried to connect based on various articles, but it doesn't work.

I confirmed the manual connection with the following settings.

・Phase 2 certification: MSCHAPV2

・CA certificate: Use system certificate

・Domain: Domain string

・ID: ID character string

・Password: Password character string

Logcat displays "Enterprise configuration is insecure" during addNetworkSuggestions.

The code of the Wifi connection processing part is as follows.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

WifiConfiguration targetConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
targetConfig.SSID = '"' + targetSSID + '"';
targetConfig.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
targetConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
targetConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
WifiEnterpriseConfig ec = new WifiEnterpriseConfig();
ec.setIdentity(userName);
ec.setPassword(password);
ec.setDomainSuffixMatch("domain.name");
ec.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
ec.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2);
targetConfig.enterpriseConfig = ec;

final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion1 =
        new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                .setSsid(targetSSID)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                .setWpa2EnterpriseConfig(targetConfig.enterpriseConfig)
                .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true)
                .build();

final List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(suggestion1);
int result = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(list);

if (result == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
    Log.d("testLog", "success");
} else {
    Log.d("testLog", "failed");
}
```

Comment: I feel that the answers to the following questions are closely related.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059907/how-to-set-use-system-certificates-with-wifienterpriseconfig

Comment: any update? I need help on this as well, do we have to add a cert?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you remove the call to `setWpa2Passphrase()` which is redundant with the call to `WifiEnterpriseConfig.setPassword()`.

I deduced that because on my Android 10 device, when I try with your code it raises the following exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: only one of setIsEnhancedOpen
> setWpa2Passphrase,setWpa3Passphrase, setWpa2EnterpriseConfig or
> setWpa3EnterpriseConfig can be invoked for network specifier

Furthermore, note that the `WifiConfiguration` part of your code is not used
in your code and is deprecated.